# How to play system sound in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, web, alert, flutter-web, ringtone

How to play system sound in flutter web without using any packages in all platform ?
I've tried `await SystemSound.play(SystemSoundType.alert);` but no alert tone played.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web platform currently does not support playing sounds, so this call will yield no behavior on that platform.

source : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemSound/play.html